# How to get the location using GSM (Cellular Network) in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, geolocation, gsm

I am working on a project in blackberry where i don't have GPS and i want to get the location in which i am there from time to time. I found that it is possible using a third member like opencellid.org. But i don't want to depend on other person. Is it possible to get the location coordinates in this way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following links which gives very useful information about locations services in blackberry

[Location-Based Services](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/lbs-summary.html#GPS)

[Location APIs – Start to finish](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949)

Google provides location apis which you can use to find out the lat/longs. Its very easy. All you do is create a json request with your current cellid , and send the request to google. You get the lat/long from the google response.